# The main view doesn't autoresize, odd behaviour

Tags: objective-c

Everything seems to work fine except when the device orientation is changed.
Every time it changes the method bellow gets called:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

The problem is that no matter how many times i rotate the device the main view's
(self.view) size doesn't change to what it actually should be.

```
2013-03-12 14:33:32.504 WBDEMO[888:907] {{0, 20}, {768, 1004}}
2013-03-12 14:33:33.929 WBDEMO[888:907] {{0, 0}, {748, 1024}}
2013-03-12 14:33:35.357 WBDEMO[888:907] {{0, 20}, {768, 1004}}
2013-03-12 14:33:36.009 WBDEMO[888:907] {{0, 0}, {748, 1024}}
```

At Portrait Mode the size should be {768, 1004} while at Landscape mode the size
should be {1024, 748}

I have tried setting it's autoresizingMask to:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

But it still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Code for logging:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
}
```

Comment: include the codeused for logging

Comment: Have you implemented - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}  ?

Comment: Yes, both shouldAutorotate and - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation since the latter is deprecated.

Comment: Is the NIB set to autoresize?

Comment: Where is the autoresize property? Do you mean Autoresize Subviews?

Comment: Actually i did code the same.. i am also not able to understand y it is logging wrong frame size. +1 for the good question. Eager to know the answer.

Comment: I can't ship a product that has bugs no matter what other method i can use to solve it. I'll be waiting for the answer.

Comment: Is `self.view.bounds` correct?